# Inversion of words in Maui Blazor

Tags: blazor, maui

## Always when I start a new project it looks like this picture How do I fix it

[image: this is the Pic]

I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: It looks like the BlazorWebView is defaulting to RTL text direction - probably based on your language settings. You could try adding a `dir` to your html tag like this `<html dir='ltr'>`

Comment: If that were the case would the individual characters still be facing the right?  It looks to me like the entire UI is mirrored

Comment: Did you try to run the project on the android or the ios platform?